# Using PowerShell check selected drive free space

Tags: powershell

I want to run a  PowerShell command if drive has X amount free storage capacity.

using following command we can get the free space information.

```
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='D:'" | Select-Object {$_.FreeSpace/1gb}
```

i tried like this

```
$space = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object {$_.FreeSpace/1gb}



If ($space -gt 10) {


Copy-Item -Path "C:\1\*" -Destination "C:\2\" -recurse -Force -Verbose
   
}
```

Sorry I have very limited knowledge about PowerShell. i getting error `objects are not the same type`. I think it's because `$space` giving text name information before the digit.

Comment: The linked duplicate contains more details, but in short: to simply calculate a _value_ based on a pipeline input object, use `ForEach-Object`: `Select-Object { $_.FreeSpace/1gb }` -> `ForEach-Object { $_.FreeSpace/1gb }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing against the object and not the free space value itself

Change `If ($space -gt 10)` to `If ($space.'$_.FreeSpace/1gb' -gt 10)` to compare against the number inside the object held in `$space`.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-WMIObject` is deprecated you should try to start migrating to the CIM cmdlets. In this case `Get-CimInstance`

```
$FreeSpace = (Get-CimInstance Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'").FreeSpace / 1GB
If( $FreeSpace -gt 10) {
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\1\*" -Destination "C:\2\" -recurse -Force -Verbose
}
```

I prefer the Win32_Volume class for this task, though the above should work fine with Win32_LogicalVolume.

For more on the change from WMI to Cim, take a look at these articles:

[Introduction to CIM Cmdlets](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets/)

[Scripting Guys CIM Vs WMI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/)

Comment: thank you, i still learning powershell. i have very little knowledge about powershell.